# DBCC RESULTS - 1719 Errors - how best to proceed with repair

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

A production database which is continually updated with external data has reported following an integrity check 1719 errors.

These can be grouped into:

116 x

```
<Dbcc ID="1" Error="8909" Severity="16" State="1">Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc un
it ID 14918418583781376 (type Unknown), page ID (1:358049) contains an incorrect page ID in its page header. The 
PageId in the page header = (45:3473461).</Dbcc>
```

Summarised:

```
 <Dbcc ID="118" Error="8954" Severity="10" State="1">CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 118 consistency errors 
not associated with any single object.</Dbcc>
```

544 x

```
<Dbcc ID="119" Error="8928" Severity="16" State="1">Object ID 854294103, index ID 6, partition ID 720575941117214
72, alloc unit ID 72057594157203456 (type In-row data): Page (1:358048) could not be processed.  See other errors
 for details.</Dbcc>
```

Summarised:

```
<Dbcc ID="663" Error="8990" Severity="10" State="1">CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 544 consistency errors 
in table 'Rpm.TrainRecord' (object ID 854294103).</Dbcc>
```

1021 x

```
<Dbcc ID="1684" Error="8909" Severity="16" State="1">Table error: Object ID 1327343793, index ID 4, partition ID 
72057594114670592, alloc unit ID 72057594160611328 (type In-row data), page ID (1:7031943) contains an incorrect 
page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = (1:4795983).</Dbcc>
```

Summarised:

```
<Dbcc ID="1685" Error="8990" Severity="10" State="1">CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 1021 consistency error
s in table 'Audit.AuditLog' (object ID 1327343793).</Dbcc>
```

31 x

```
<Dbcc ID="1716" Error="8928" Severity="16" State="1">Object ID 1349579846, index ID 7, partition ID 7205759410936
2176, alloc unit ID 72057594154647552 (type In-row data): Page (3:600863) could not be processed.  See other erro
rs for details.</Dbcc>
```

Summarised:

```
<Dbcc ID="1717" Error="8990" Severity="10" State="1">CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 31 consistency errors 
in table 'Rpm.AlarmEventRecord' (object ID 1349579846).</Dbcc>
```

The end output is

```
<Dbcc ID="1720" Error="8958" Severity="10" State="1">repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the e
rrors found by DBCC CHECKDB ([databasename]).</Dbcc>
```

We have backups, it seems the issue has come about following a move of the DB from one server to another (over last weekend). Checking the old server, there are no consistency errors at all.

The database functions fine and can be backed up / restored.

I'm guessing I need to repair with data loss - but can I do anything better than that?

Comment: If the issues happened after a move to a new server, I'd recommend verifying the disk on that new server isn't failing / corrupt itself (outside of the database). You wouldn't want to fix your database corruption only for it to happen again. Also please provide which version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: I'm monitoring the number of inconsistencies to see if they increase for this reason. It is a VM in azure on a dedicated data disk - so I would be surprised. It's server 2019 ENT

Comment: You would need to run data corruption checks at the OS level against the disk directly to be sure. You won't be able to determine if that's the case from within your database. Regardless, it's not uncommon for that to be the case based on the order of events you described.

Comment: Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 536852479 KB total disk space.
 365828920 KB in 116 files.
       104 KB in 25 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
     82595 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 170940860 KB available on disk.

I think the disk looks ok.

Comment: @J.D. you were right. please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who faces this specific situation, the fix was the resize the VM in Azure.

Very odd, but merely resizing the VM, and putting it back to the size it was resolved the issue.

I can only assume it moved the disks to another cluster and the original cluster had an issue of some sort which bubbled up as an SQL IO / consistency error.